# screen goes black for a second randomly

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel-graphics, bug-reporting

Randomly, my monitor's image blanks for a moment then returns. I am facing this problem after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as the only OS on this PC; id did not occur back when Windows was on it. I added:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and updated then rebooted, but I still have the blanking problem.

I'm using DisplayPort output (see pictures below) cables as I was before installing Ubuntu, and didn't have this issue.  Changing to 50Hz refresh did not help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Random blackouts are often a hardware issue. 1) Is the video adapter firmly fitted in its PCIe slot? 2) Please disconnect / firmly reconnect the monitor power cable. 3) Please disconnect / firmly reconnect the video data cable from PC to monitor. 4) Please look at https://superuser.com/a/1502472/264083 then tell us the kind of fitting on each end of that cable. 5) Have you tried another video data cable and power cable? 7) What is the make and model of the monitor? Please click [edit] to add this info to the question; don't use Add Comment, instead click [edit].

Comment: And, FYI, the Intel UHD graphics drivers in the latest kernel is the most up-to-date driver available. Linus does a good job of making sure those are updated, so it's unlikely any driver via a PPA will help with an Intel graphics driver issue.

Comment: @K7AAY i updated the question but i remember that on windows i didn't have this issue.

Comment: Then, please do troubleshooting steps 1-3 and 5-7 above. Please click [edit] to add this info to the question; _please_ don't use Add Comment, instead click [edit] because comment space is limited. You can delete your comments above since I put their content into your question.

Comment: I still have this problem on ubuntu 21.04, using latest display.